# Incorrect weeks calculation in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, week-number

I use node.js with moment 2.9.0

```
var moment = require("moment");
var d = moment.utc([2014, 11, 27]);
var iso = d.toISOString();
var week = d.week();
```

shows iso = "2014-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"
and week is 52.

But if `var d = moment.utc([2014, 11, 28]);`

iso is 2014-12-28T00:00:00.000Z

week is 1. Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer can be found [in the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/):

> The week of the year varies depending on which day is the first day of
>   the week (Sunday, Monday, etc), and which week is the first week of the year.
>
> For example, in the United States, Sunday is the first day of the week.
>   The week with January 1st in it is the first week of the year.

So, week #1 of 2015 (by this function) is:

- 2014-12-28  (Sunday)
- 2014-12-29  (Monday)
- 2014-12-30  (Tuesday)
- 2014-12-31  (Wednesday)
- 2015-01-01  (Thursday)
- 2015-01-02  (Friday)
- 2015-01-03  (Saturday)

It's also worth mentioning that moment also has the [`isoWeek`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-week/) function, which conforms to the [ISO 8601 week numbering system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

Comment: var d = moment.utc([2014, 11, 28]).isoWeek(); -> 52  and
var d = moment.utc([2014, 11, 29]).isoWeek(); -> 1   isoWeek works incorrectly too?

Comment: They both work correctly.  ISO Weeks start on Monday, as described in the third paragraph of [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).  I think perhaps you're just confused about the fact that a year's first week could actually start in the prior year.

Comment: Hi @MattJohnson ! 
I want to start week from thursday because of my project requirement.
Is there any way to start week from thursday? so that first date of week#1 can be 2017-01-05 ?

Comment: @user2899728 yes, see the moment docs on customizing locale dow/doy.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and it was not `week()` that helped, but `isoWeek()`

for me I get week number like this

`moment('2022-12-26', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isoWeek()   // return 52`

`moment('2022-12-26', 'YYYY-MM-DD').week()   // return 53`